# Leaflet works with Bing 8 Maps?

Tags: leaflet, bing-maps

Bing 7 support is about to end and hence I need to migrate to Bing 8. I am using leaflet through which I am getting the static tiles from bing Maps REST services (this is through my understanding of the code of leaflet to integrate bing in it, kindly correct if I am wrong).

So since I am using Leaflet with Bing, looking at this I suppose there is nothing for me to change in the migration. 
But how to know whether it is working correctly with the updated version?

Where are the static images coming from when I use the REST services?

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34563.bing-maps-v7-to-v8-migration-guide.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using leaflet you are not using Bing Maps v7. Bing Maps v7 and v8 are standalone java script map controls just like leaflet. Leaflet pulls in map tiles using the bing maps rest services which are the main services powering all bing maps controls and many 3rd party map controls such as leaflet. These services are not being retired.

In summary, you don't need to migrate your leaflet app as it isn't related to bing maps v7.